# Notificação JQuery aparecer apenas 1 vez

Tags: jquery

Como faço para que, conforme o código abaixo, a notificação apareça apenas uma vez a cada acesso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<script src="assets/plugins/notification/js/bootstrap-growl.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    'use strict';
    $(window).on('load',function(){
      function notify(message, type){
          $.growl({
              message: message
          },{
              type: type,
              allow_dismiss: false,
              label: 'Cancel',
              className: 'btn-xs btn-warning',
              placement: {
                  from: 'top',
                  align: 'right'
              },
              spacing: 10,
              z_index: 999999,
              delay: 10000,
              animate: {
                      enter: 'animated fadeInRight',
                      exit: 'animated fadeOutRight'
              }
          });
      };
          notify('<span style="color: #000;font-size: 14px; font-weight: bold">ENVIAR MENSAGEM HOJE</span>&nbsp;<button type="button" class="close" data-growl="dismiss"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>', 'warning');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Experimentou `sessionStorage`?

Comment: Olá Guilherme, não saco muito de Jquery. Como eu poderia aplicar sessionStorage nesse código?

Comment: sessionStorage não é jQuery => https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como o amigo Guilherme Nascimento falou nos comentários, é possível utilizar o `sessionStorage`, gravando uma chave, digamos "exibiuMensagem" e checar se o valor dela é "true" (ou "exibido" ou alguma outra coisa, você escolhe) antes de exibir a mensagem. Ficaria mais ou menos assim:

```
if(localStorage.getItem('exibiuMensagem') != true){
    notify(...);
    localStorage.setItem('exibiuMensagem', true);
}
```

Assim, a cada acesso, o `if` checaria se esse item já existe e tem valor 'true', caso não, ele exibiria a mensagem e salvaria o item.

Além disso, é bom remover o item quando o usuário fechar o browser, para que da próxima vez a mensagem seja exibida novamente. Dá pra fazer isso com essa função:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function{
   localStorage.removeItem('exibiuMensagem');
};
```